# Change names in my code php breadcrumbs

Tags: javascript, php

I need a little help here I have a breadcrumbs in php. My directory is like this:

```
folder/name.php
```

and using this code I get on output like this:

```
Home » folder » name
```

What I want to do is to put name that I want instead of the code gets the name of folder and file.

Here's my code:

```
<?php 
    $path = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    $parts = explode('/',$path);
    if (count($parts) < 2)
    {
    echo("home");
    }
    else
    {
    echo ("<a href=\"/\">Home</a> &raquo; ");
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($parts); $i++)
        {
        if (!strstr($parts[$i],"."))
            {
            echo("<a href=\"");
            for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {echo $parts[$j]."/";};
            echo("\">". str_replace('-', ' ', $parts[$i])."</a> » ");
            }
        else
            {
            $str = $parts[$i];
            $pos = strrpos($str,".");
            $parts[$i] = substr($str, 0, $pos);
            echo str_replace('-', ' ', $parts[$i]);
            };
        };
    };  
?>
```

Second code

```
<?php
    $Pages = array(
      '/NewTgoTv' => 'Clothes',
      '/NewTgoTv/33.php' => 'Something'
    );

    $path = $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"];
    $parts = explode('/',$path);
    if (count($parts) < 2)
    {
    echo("home");
    }
    else
    {
    echo ("<a href=\"/\">Home</a> &raquo; ");
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($parts); $i++)
        {
        if (!strstr($parts[$i],"."))
            {
            echo("<a href=\"");
            for ($j = 0; $j <= $i; $j++) {echo $parts[$j]."/";};
            echo("\">". str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]])."</a> &raquo; ");
            }
        else
            {
            $str = $parts[$i];
            $pos = strrpos($str,".");
            $parts[$i] = substr($str, 0, $pos);
            echo str_replace('-', ' ', $Pages[$parts[$i]]);
            };
        };
    };  
?>
```

Comment: You want to change "Home > Folder > Name" to something like "Home > Folder > AnotherName"? ....Sorry I don't get it.

Comment: thanks for your replay dear . on my localhost i have it like this " http://localhost/myfolder/page1.php " and output i get like this " Home » myfolder » page1 " ut i don't want it to be like this. yes it gets directory right but the names i want to put it like, for Home it's ok and for myfolder i want it something else and for page1 i want it something else also on output

Comment: on output it must be like "Home > AnotherName > AnotherName"

Comment: it should only change names on output for myfolder and page1

Comment: I think you need a way to "trade" the names then, like str_replace($yourFirstArray, $yourSecondArray, $theMainArray), where: $yourFirstArray equals the values to replace, like "page1.php", then, $yourSecondArray contains the trade like "My page" and finally $theMainArray contains your breadcrumb array, so in this way you manually need to change the names...or, you can use a database for that.

Comment: dear, if you just check my question i have add second code another user said it will work like this but i am getting error some how. can you please check it and edit it for me